# pytest - patched method of a class does not return the mock value

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

My code is fairly simple but i don't understand what is going on :

```
class MyDb :
   def some_func( arg ) :
    ....
```

while my test code is :

```
@mock.patch(mypkg.mydb)
@pytest.mark.parametrize( func_dummy_value ) :
  ( [ { "id" : 1234 } ] )
def test_simple ( mock_db , dummy_value ) :
  mock_db.some_func.return_value = dummy_value
```

So from where I call it I do have sth like :

```
db = MyDb()
print db
print db.some_func()
```

I was expecting the last one to print the dummy value I have given when running the test. Instead I get :

```
<MagicMock name='MyDb()' id='140018446236496'>
<MagicMock name='MyDb().some_func()' id='140018443991696'>
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Read [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have but I don't understand how it solves my problem. I have patched the class and I am calling one of its methods which should return the dummy value. This doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some_func` is a instance method, so it is called on an instance of MyDb, not the class itself. An instance is a return value from calling a class. So you need to bear that in mind when you patch.

```
mock_db.return_value.some_func.return_value = dummy_value
```